# r for loop to import xlsx files in individual data frame

Tags: r, linux, for-loop, dataframe, import-from-excel

I want to import 50 xlsx files into R with each is an individual data frame so that I can for loop individually for downstream calculation.

import:

```
1.name_input.xlsx
2.name_input.xlsx
3.name_input.xlsx
4.name_input.xlsx
.
.
.
50.name_input.xlsx



listy <- list.files(path = "./",pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = FALSE,recursive = TRUE) 

for ( i in 1:length(listy)) { filename=listy[i] data=read.xls(file = i,header=TRUE) assign(x=filename,value = data)}
```

But it doesn't work, so is there other methods to work it out?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a typo? Should pattern = "*.xlsx"?

Comment: Typo in this post. my command doesn't work.

Comment: @Marichyasana can you help me ?

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` in conjunction with `read_excel()` from the **readxl** package to read in each file in your list of files

```
require(readxl)

listy <- list.files(path = "./",pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = FALSE,recursive = TRUE)

all_data <- lapply(listy,read_excel)
```

The resulting `all_data` object will be a list where each list element corresponds to a file in `listy`